# Looking for a way to: R Studio accessing files on windows AWS server

Tags: r, rstudio, sparklyr

I have installed R studio on my local laptop and trying to access files located in AWS server (Windows).

I do not want to use FTP protocol. 
What are other possible ways to remotely access the files located on a remote server?

How to use SCP/SSH protocol to access files on AWS server?

My objective is to work and analyze log files generated by a remote server.

I am looking to find a way to get through to access the files first. Once my first hurdle is achieved, later I'll import the files into spark environment using "sparklyr".

Kindly help me get access to these files

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://serverfault.com/questions/150369/how-to-copy-files-to-amazon-ec2-windows-instance-from-my-local-machine

Comment: Thanks..I was busy and diverted my efforts on another project. Will try out these steps when I get time to work on this. My main issue was to load the data directly into R as R data-frame from the server.